# Filtering list on multiple conditions

Tags: python, list, performance, filter

What is the most efficient way to filter multiple lists through multiple conditions?  Ex.

```
time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
y = [5, 5, 8, 8, 8]
```

I want to find the indices conditioning on all 3 lists such that

```
time < 4
x > 2
y > 7
```

which should give me the result

```
[2]
```

The pandas method if the above data was in a dataframe would be

```
(df['time'] < 4) & (df['x'] > 2) & (df['y'] > 7)
```

The brute force method would be something like

```
idx = []
for i in range(len(time)):
    if time[i] < 4 and x[i] > 2 and y[i] > 7:
        idx.append(i)
```

However, these variables can get quite large (500,000+), so a for loop would be quite inefficient.

Comment: The loop is O(n) - linear runtime. How is that inefficient?

Comment: How is [3] the correct answer?  The only index that fits all requirements is 2.

Comment: @Prune Sorry I was working on something in Matlab which is 1 index, not 0 based.  Fixed

Comment: So why not put the values in a dataframe?

Comment: @Harsh You're right, even for a list with length 500000, it only takes ~0.05 seconds to loop through it

Comment: @Nick The code is being deployed to a platform where pandas is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like below

```
[k for k,g in enumerate(zip(time,x,y)) if g[0]<4 and g[1]>2 and g[2]>7]
```

or faster (Thank @Steven Rumbalski)

```
[k for k, (_t, _x, _y) in enumerate(zip(time, x, y)) if _t < 4 and _x > 2 and _y > 7]
```

which gives

```
[2]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a general question, are list comprehension actually faster than for loops?

Comment: @so_many_questions Sorry that I have no idea whether it would be faster than `for` loops

Comment: How is this any better than O(n)? In fact it will be slower than the loop in the question

Comment: If every ounce of speed really matters, subscripting `g` might slow this down a little. `[k for k, (_t, _x, _y) in enumerate(zip(time, x, y)) if _t < 4 and _x > 2 and _y > 7]` might be faster. One tuple unpack might be faster than three subscripts.

Comment: @Harsh.  It's O(n) no matter what.  The pandas version hides the O(n) in C code, but it's still there.

Comment: @Harsh it is `O(n)`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I said it is not better than O(n) which was the loop in the question. In fact, for this question, if you will time your code, it might have slight disadvantage over a simple for loop. Your solution will theoretically still be O(n)  but practically might be off by few millis.

Comment: @so_many_questions: I timed the for-loop version against various versions of this list comprehension answer and found that the for-loop version is *faster* except when the list comprehension written *without* `enumerate()`:  `[i for i in range(len(time)) if time[i] < 4 and x[i] > 2 and y[i] > 7]` and then they perform the same.  This is surprising because often list comprehensions are faster.

Comment: Also, my suggestion of tuple-unpacking over subscripting was incorrect.  When I tested it tuple-unpacking was slower.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Interesting, I did a quick test myself, and found that list comprehension was much faster for lists of size 500000

Answer (score 1):

I `%timeit` 3 methods.  The apply method showed the best speed - 25% better then py loop, and 2x faster than DF basic compare.

```
def foo(df):
    return list(df[(df.time < 4) & (df.x > 2) & (df.y > 7)].time)

print("\nMETHOD 1: DF comparison")
%timeit foo(df) 
%timeit foo(df) 
%timeit foo(df) 

def foo(t, x, y):
    idx = []
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if t[i] < 4 and x[i] > 2 and y[i] > 7:
            idx.append(i)
    return(idx)
print("\nMETHOD 2: py loop")
%timeit foo(time, x, y) 
%timeit foo(time, x, y) 
%timeit foo(time, x, y) 

def foo(df):
    return df.apply(lambda r: r.time if ((r.time < 4) & (r.x > 2)& (r.y > 7)) else np.nan, axis=1).unique()

print("\nMETHOD 3: DF apply")
%timeit foo(df) 
%timeit foo(df) 
%timeit foo(df)

METHOD 1: DF comparison
698 µs ± 19.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
696 µs ± 6.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
690 µs ± 16.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

METHOD 2: py loop
481 µs ± 11.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
468 µs ± 4.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
466 µs ± 4.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

METHOD 3: DF apply
355 ms ± 5.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
356 ms ± 10.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
360 ms ± 8.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: OP states in the comments that they can't use pandas

Comment: Honestly surprised a for loop is faster than df comparison though

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - interesting.    I created 3 lists using [np.random.randint(1000) for n in range(10000)].... I'm using Py3.7 on MacPro.

Answer (score -1):

```
time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
y = [5, 5, 8, 8, 8]

# Get True/False lists
t = [x<4 for x in time]
x1 = [i > 2 for i in x]
y2 = [i > 7 for i in y]

# Bitwise and
b = [x&y for x,y in zip(t,x1)]
# Bitwise and again, with index lookup of remianing True
time[[x&y for x,y in zip(b,y2)].index(True)]
```

Output

```
3
```

Comment: This seems even more inefficient